# Update partial database from entity Migration - aspnet mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have deleted and modified somes tables in database sqlserver manually, then I have deleted __MigrationHistory table...
Now, when i run "add-migration" command, it regenare commands for recreate entire structure of database, but I want to syncronize the structure from the model to database, without recreates all tables in database...

> the comnand "add-migration -ignoreChanges" is not correct, because the
>   model of website is different from database, because i have manual
>   modified somes tables.....

is possibles?

thanks

Comment: Manually match your entities to match the new database, then start using migrations again. Or delete your entities and switch to database first.

Comment: Add a migration without -IgnoreChanges and comment out all the objects that exist, leave the ones that don't. You may need to splice in some AddColumn/DropColumn commands. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration(v=vs.113).aspx